# How do I make OmniAuth Identity accept JSON post data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, omniauth

I'm using OmniAuth-Identity for log ins, and logging in using Ajax calls.  Attempts to log in passing JSON data don't work.

For instance this works:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -d "auth_key=joe@example.com&password=cheesestix" "http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/identity/callback"
```

This doesn't, it returns "invalid credentials"

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth_key":"joe@example.com","password":"cheesestix"}' "http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/identity/callback"
```

Is this a known issue?  Form encoding my data will be difficult as I'm using AngularJS.

UPDATE:

One of the rails guys fixed it by backporting JSON support into Rack.

```
gem 'rack', git: 'https://github.com/ssoroka/rack.git', branch: '1.5.2-json-support-backport'
```

I'm hesitant to post that as an answer becase I don't understand the details of Rack well enough to explain anything.  But the relevant diff is here: https://github.com/ssoroka/rack/commit/d8e2e2af6da57805d2f0906ce925ea150def31a0