# Omniauth strategy wont respond to JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm using [this Omniauth Middleware](https://github.com/SoapSeller/omniauth-facebook-access-token/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook-access-token.rb) to validate facebook access tokens form an iOS app.

This strategy is installed like so:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook_access_token, Settings.facebook.key, Settings.facebook.secret
end
```

This works wonderfully via this url:

```
/users/auth/facebook_access_token/callback?access_token=<snipped>
```

However, if I add a `.json` to the end of the path my route still triggers but it fails to trigger the middleware.

```
/users/auth/facebook_access_token/callback.json?access_token=<snipped>
```

I know it fails to trigger because I can see log activity related to strategy when it triggers, and when it fails I get none. It also does not populate `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` with the data I need.

My route that picks up both of those paths is:

```
match 'users/auth/facebook_access_token/callback' => 'omniauth_callbacks#facebook', via: :all
```

So how can I can get the middleware to trigger when I use a `.json` request format, so that I detect that and render a JSON response?

---

Related but *mostly* unsolved: [How do I make OmniAuth Identity accept JSON post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658498/how-do-i-make-omniauth-identity-accept-json-post-data)